# trying to upgrade from laravel 7 to laravel 9 but I get this error:

Tags: php, laravel

- macsidigital/laravel-api-client[3.3.0, ..., 3.3.4] require macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-client ^1.2 -> satisfiable by macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-clie
  nt[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.x-dev, v1.x-dev].

  - macsidigital/laravel-zoom[4.1.5, ..., 4.1.9] require macsidigital/laravel-api-client ^3.3 -> satisfiable by macsidigital/laravel-api-client[3.3.0, ..
    ., 3.3.5].
  - macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-client[1.2.0, ..., 1.2.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-
    dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
  - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0
    .0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
  - mcamara/laravel-localization v1.7.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.2.0||~5.3.0||~5.4.0||~5.5.0||~5.6.0||~5.7.0||~5.8.0||^6.0||^7.0||^8.0||^9.0 -> sati
    sfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
  - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.1 (conflict analysis result)

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "codezero/laravel-unique-translation": "^3.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "2.4",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.3",
        "macsidigital/laravel-zoom": "^4.1",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "v1.7.0",
        "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.6",
        "yoeunes/toastr": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear I think. The chain of dependencies of laravel-api-client for the version you are using does not work with Laravel 9, perhaps there is a newer version of that you can switch to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update packages to support Laravel 9.

You can check the latest version of each package, else, remove the package, upgrade Laravel then re-install the package.

macsidigital/laravel-zoom for instance, has version 5 available to support Laravel 9, but your composer.json ties the installation to the 4.x releases.